# How to populate a GridView from a Cursor with custom layout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I did some research but wasn't able to find a good example.

Current setup:

```
ArrayList<String> arrCursor = new ArrayList<String>();
List<mydata> md = mydatabase.getthedata("1");
for (mydata cn1 : md) {
    arrCursor.add(cn1.getTheFirst());
    arrCursor.add(cn1.getTheSecond());
}
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrCursor);
gv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //the gridview
```

GridView layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.chao">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvalldata"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The above only displays a simple list rather than a custom one.

To start the custom adapter process, I have setup an item list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvfirst"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvsecond" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I add a custom adapter which will show the gridview using the item list layout and in boxes.

What I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: Found an example: http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/showcase/8/...

Comment: The `ArrayAdapter` will work for your application, but I'd suggest using a `CursorAdapter` instead.  It will eliminate iterating over the data set and copying it into the array.  It is much more efficient and will update the data immediately when notifyDataSetChanged() is called on the adapter.  [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) is an example.

Comment: @GaryBak Something like that might work. I am testing it out. Thanks. Instead of a ListView I am using GridView.

Comment: @GaryBak That guide actually helped me write my own adapter implementing a baseadapter. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work make custom adapter and set that adapter to gridview
gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList,prgmImages));

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    Context context;
 int [] imageId;
      private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                 getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;

             rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
             holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

         holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
         holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

         rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Comment: so instead of sending `prgmNameList` and `prgmImages` should I send the `arrCursor` and use that instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try inserting your own custom layout (*R.layout.custom_layout*) in the ArrayAdapter constructor instead of the android one (***android.**R.layout.simple_list_item_1*)

so E.g
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_layout, arrCursor);

Comment: The app crashes when I use that.

Comment: Yeah sorry, forgot that you also need a custom adapter for that. But I hope you got sorted.